# Best way to use lokijs with angular2 and electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new to nodejs and electron development. I'm building a desktop application which i need to use [lokijs](http://lokijs.org/) as the database engine. Is it correct to initialize the communicate with lokijs inside the electron rendering process ? Or should i do the lokijs communication in main process and communicate via ipc ? What is the best practice to access lokijs inside electron together with angular.

Comment: LokiJS says it works in both node.js and browser. If you were asking specifically about how to use LokiJS, I'd suggest you put that in the title. If you asking more generally about best practice, it would be worth emphasizing that in the body of your question (and perhaps using an example other than LokiJS?)

Answer (score 0):

Make a child process to the access the file system by sending
ls and cd .. terminal command
it will list all the files and folders access it via standard input and output.

Comment: I'm more interested in finding the best way to use lokijs with angular + electron